# php script for selecting/inserting, only succeeds for one row

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I made a fairly simple script to take records from a development database, and for each selected record insert it into production and get the newly created ID.

This "Works" but only for one record. WHen I run this script, it successfully connects, selects, inserts, and prints the newly inserted record's ID but then the script just stops and when I check the database only one new record is there, even though there are over 500 records in the source table

Is it just becuase I'm using While instead of foreach? I think I've done something similar before with a while loop but this isjust dying on me after one successful attempt.

```
if($DB2connDEV && $DB2connPROD){

    $getDevelopment = "
        SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE; // there are over 500 records in here
    ";

    $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connDEV, $getDevelopment);

    while($gettingDevelopment = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){

        $originalID = $gettingDevelopment['identity'];

        $insertTable = "INSERT INTO testing_insert_php (name) VALUES ($originalID)";
        $getIdentity = "SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS LASTID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1";

        $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connPROD, $insertTable);
        $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connPROD, $getIdentity);
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);
        $ret = $row['LASTID'];


        if($ret) {
            echo "Last Insert ID is : " . $ret . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "No Last insert ID.\n";
        }
    }

    odbc_close($DB2connPROD);
}
```

Comment: Is it perhaps "failing silently" on the INSERT or subsequent SELECT due to eg a constraint error?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I added different error outs and didn't get anything. The traceback shows that the insert was successful and then it just stopped. Do you suggest a better way to check for silent fails in this case?

Comment: The comment is based on what I see (or don't see as the case my be). No check of the INSERT/SELECT result(s), nor knowledge of what php error logging is in play. And there's no explicit commit, nor do I know if it's necessary.  I also have to take your word for it that there are 500 rows in `TEST_TABLE` and the db connection objects are correct. From a troubleshooting perspective I would change it to a `foreach` and learn whether the problem is the `while` or elsewhere.

Comment: May be you shouldn't use the same variable `$stmt` to reference three different SQL statements. After the first iteration `$stmt` will reference the result of `SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()...`.